# Inbound TCP/IP Connection Failed: Handshake Header Error

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've not been able to locate an answer to this although it's been asked often. In a very simple case (directly from a tutorial) I am getting the above error message. I kind of understand what the error is trying to say: the action client is exiting and the action server is complaining about it disappearing. But I don't understand why. Is there further tear down needed in the action client so the server doesn't complain?

I am running melodic on ubuntu 18.04. Here's the source code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import actionlib
from prrexamples.msg import TimerAction, TimerGoal, TimerResult

# Declare the node
rospy.init_node('timer_action_client')

# Get the method to talk to the action
client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('timer', TimerAction)

# Now just wait for it  to come up.
client.wait_for_server()
rospy.loginfo("Action server detected")

# Create the TimerGoal objet
goal = TimerGoal()

# Set it up
goal.time_to_wait = rospy.Duration.from_sec(5.0)

# And now tell the action to begin working on the goal
client.send_goal(goal)

# Block until the action says the job is done
client.wait_for_result()

# Print the result.
rospy.loginfo('Time elapsed: %f'%(client.get_result().time_elapsed.to_sec()))
```

and

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import time
import actionlib
from prrexamples.msg import TimerAction, TimerGoal, TimerResult

# Action Request Comes in
def do_timer(goal):
    start_time = time.time()
    time.sleep(goal.time_to_wait.to_sec())
    result = TimerResult()
    result.time_elapsed = rospy.Duration.from_sec(time.time() - start_time)
    result.updates_sent = 0
    server.set_succeeded(result)

# Declare that we are a node
rospy.init_node('timer_action_server')

# Declare that this node will handle actions
# When action requests come in, call do_timer method
server = actionlib.SimpleActionServer('timer', TimerAction, do_timer, False)

# Start it up
server.start()

# Wait until ^c
rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329002/inbound-tcp/ip-connection-failed:-connection-from-sender-terminated-before-handshake-header-received.-0-bytes-were-received.-please-check-sender-for-additional-details/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2019-07-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2019-10-28**:
I'm running into this too. I think the teardown is correct, could be a bug in actionlib. Consider creating [an issue on their github](https://github.com/ros/actionlib/issues/new). I'm also noticing that this warning only pops up occasionally.

**Comment by [Bing Han](https://answers.ros.org/users/70899/bing-han/) on 2021-02-25**:
I have the same question "[WARN] [1614305288.280276, 0.000000]: Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: connection from sender terminated before handshake header received. 0 bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details."
Do you deal with it? Please give me some advice, thank you!

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2021-02-26**:
@Bing Han Please don't provide answers that are not answers. This is a Q&A site not a discussion forum. I've reposted your answer as a question comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you can use "del" inner function temporory.

It make client to be disconnected normally.

---

Originally posted by [hanback114](https://answers.ros.org/users/55734/hanback114/) with karma: 16 on 2020-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0